# Large desktop and small desktop element responsive problem

Tags: css, media-queries

I have problem that i have cart main div element and problem is to make mobile responsive correctly, in laptop ( width:1024) or less working correctly, because i using  :

```
@media (min-width: 801px)
#cart-modal {
    left: 59%;
}
```

but in large screen ( width like : 1920px ) i used :

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 801px) and (max-width: 1920px)
#cart-modal {
    left: 69%;
    width: 600px;
}
```

not working !

I want just when i open large screen this cart should be left:69% and when i open laptop left:59%

Please Help me, Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You've set both queries min-width the same. Now, when you open page on small screen both queries are applied but the second is executed because it's more up to date.

The first one should be something like this:

```
@media (min-width: 801px) and (max-width: 1920px)
#cart-modal {
    left: 59%;
}
```

And the second one should be:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1920px)
#cart-modal {
    left: 69%;
    width: 600px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks , but not working , i checked desktop version and same it see only this code

Comment: @media (min-width: 801px) and (max-width: 1920px)
#cart-modal {
    left: 59%;
}

Answer (score 0):

See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) for properly constructing @media queries. In this case, your queries are missing parent braces `{ ... }`, and should look like this:

```
@media (min-width: 801px) {
  #cart-modal {
      left: 59%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1920px) {
  #cart-modal {
      left: 69%;
      width: 600px;
  }
}
```